# How can I get the rows along with row count in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following query:

```
select 
    *, 
    count(pk_id) as row_count
from employee 
group by 
    pk_id
```

But I am not getting 1 as the row_count value for every column.
How can I get the total number of rows returned as the result of the query?
Can someone please help?

And one more thing is I don't want to write any subquery **:(**

Comment: _rows along with row count in SQL Query_: Do you say that if your query returns 100 rows, you need this "100" also somewhere in the results?

Comment: What exactly do you want the query to return?  Just the total number of rows?  Or do you want it to return 1,2,3, as the rows increase? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: In Sql Server and Oracle you would write `SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION  BY NULL) FROM tblUsers` but I dont know if that works in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered either just counting the rows as you receive them in whatever's consuming this result set, or just using [FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)? Is there some reason you need the rowcount to appear as a *column* in the result set?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was facing the same problem, i.e with LIMIT clause :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
select 
    *, 
    count(*) as row_count
from employee 
group by 
    pk_id
```

Comment: Here pk_id is a field name in the table. But what is count(id)?

Comment: id is supposed to be the primary key for that table ... if pk_id IS the primary key, then it is normal to return 1 for each column and the `GROUP BY` has no effects, because each pk_id is unique. Although, I edited the query - try it now and tell us the results

Comment: count(*) returns the same '1' for each row.